# C# Registration Steam

Tags: c#, registration, steam

It is impossible to register.  Writes:

```
{\"bSuccess\":false,\"details\":\"captcha data missing!\"}
```

I checked all the CAPTCHA correctly.  The request also seems true.  What's wrong?

PS I using xNet

```
 public bool accaunt_create(AccauntData ad)
    {

        HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
        httpRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        httpRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36 OPR/32.0.1948.38";
        httpRequest.Cookies = cook;
        httpRequest.AddParam("accountname", ad.accountname);
        httpRequest.AddParam("password", ad.password);
        httpRequest.AddParam("email", ad.email);
        httpRequest.AddParam("captchagid", captchaID);
        httpRequest.AddHeader("captcha_text", ad.captcha_text);

        httpRequest.AddParam("i_agree", "1");
        httpRequest.AddParam("ticket");
        httpRequest.AddParam("count", "4");

        httpRequest.AddHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        httpRequest.AddHeader("X-Prototype-Version", "1.7");
        httpRequest.AddHeader("Accept", "text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*");

        var res = httpRequest.Post("https://store.steampowered.com/join/createaccount/").ToString();

        return false;

    }
```

Comment: might add C# tag. Clarify the question, a lot.

Comment: What is the value of `captchaID` and `ad.captcha_text` when you try to make a request?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this

```
httpRequest.AddParam("captchagid", captchaID);
```

have to be this:

```
httpRequest.AddParam("captchaid", captchaID);
```